# How to show the current month?

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

How to display this month? I use apexcharts and momentjs so that all months are on the chart, but it shows the real (February)

[image]

Now it shows “January,” as the current month always shows? But so that the schedule has the remaining months

```
    const chartOptions = {
  options: {
    chart: {
      id: "basic-bar"
    },
      xaxis: {
      categories: moment.months() // Months
    }
    },
    series: [
    {
      name: "Доход",
      data: [onSumArr() !== undefined ? onSumArr() : 0]
    }
  ]
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Please add your onSumArr() method also to your question, and also do console.log of moment.months() to be sure that this method gives you array of month.

From documentation of apexcharts your month and series must be like this.

```
var options = {
      series: [{
        name: "Desktops",
        data: [10, 41, 35, 51, 49, 62, 69, 91, 148]
    }],
```

and

```
    xaxis: {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep'],
    }
```

Be sure that your onSumArr() also returns the proper datas in array

Comment: Everything is displayed, I get an array with all the months, but the schedule starts in January, and not in February, this is a problem, the question is, how to always show the current month?

Comment: Use a category x-axis instead of a datetime x-axis by setting `xaxis.type: 'category'` and manually format the x values. Example - https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/candlestick-charts/category-x-axis/